# Dynamically include template elements from sub-apps in Django

Tags: django, dynamic, include

Main app contain view and template dashboard.html assign to it.
Main app can contain various number of sub-apps (with own views and template), what should dynamically fill in content in dashboard.html

I would like to achieve this without change dashboard.html or main views every single time when add new sub-app.

#### Structure of application:

```
MAIN_app/
--templates/
----dashboard.html
--views.py

--SUB_app1/
----templates/
------template_app1.html
----views.py

--SUB_app2/
----templates/
------template_app2.html
----views.py



#dashboard.html
<h1>DASHBOARD</h1>

{% template_app1.html (with context) %}

{% template_app2.html (with context) %}

{% and so on... %}
```

Each sub-app have own template with context pass by own view.

In my mind, main views function should search for views in sub-apps, and include all these views with templates.

Is there a way to do that?